# Converting this scheduling information

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm having an issue converting some scheduling information of users into a table that admins can edit.

The way my database is setup right now, it looks like:

```
user_id | day_of_week   | start_time | end_time
12      | Monday        | 8:00       | 12:00
12      | Tuesday       | 8:00       | 12:00
12      | Wednsday      | 8:00       | 12:00
12      | Thursday      | 8:00       | 12:00
12      | Friday        | 8:00       | 12:00
12      | Saturday      | 8:00       | 12:00
```

But with random times - not that that matters. Each user has 7 rows in the database.

Anyway, when I'm pulling from my database I'm getting an array of objects, one for each row that look like:

```
stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 12 [day_of_week] => Sunday [start_time] => 00:00:00 [end_time] => 00:00:00 ) 
stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 12 [day_of_week] => Monday [start_time] => 00:00:00 [end_time] => 00:00:00 )
```

The way I want to display the data, each user will have a row and the columns of that table would be User, Monday, Tuesday, etc. I'm having trouble coming up with how to do that though?

If someone could point me in the right direction or give me some thoughts on this idea, that would be great. Thanks.

**Edit:**

An example of what I'm trying to achieve

```
User_id | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday
12      | 8 - 12 | 8 - 12  | 8 - 12    | 8 - 12   | 8 - 12 | 8 - 12   | 8 - 12
13      | 6 - 11 | 8 - 13  | 8 - 15    | 6 - 14   | 9 - 11 | 8 - 22   | 8 - 23
```

Where each user has a row, showing the time when they are scheduled for that day of the week.

Comment: The columns (or fields) should be User, Monday_start_time, Monday_end_time, Tuesday_start_time etc, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely clear about what you are asking.  I think it might be how to format and display the query results.  If so, this is probably close to what you want:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM table
        WHERE user_id = $userid";   // where $userid is, for example, 12
$result = db -> query($sql);
$a = $result->result();
$rows = $a[0];

$resultarray = array();
// convert each stdClass object to an array:
foreach ($rows as $row_idx => $row)
{
    $new_array = array();
    foreach ($row as $idx => $item)
         $new_array[$idx] = $item;
    $resultarray [$row_idx] = $new_array;
}

print_r ($resultarray);  // to see what should be pretty easy to display.  For example:

echo "<table>\n";
echo "<tr>";  // create heading from field names
foreach ($resultarray[0] as $colname => $col)
      echo "<th>$colname</th>";
echo "</tr>";
// output all data rows
foreach ($resultarray as $row)
{
     echo "<tr>";
     foreach ($row as $col)   // each column of row
          echo "<td>$col</td>";
     echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Comment: The issue with this is I want the heading of a column to be a day of the week, rather than having a column for day_of_week. That's what I'm mainly having trouble doing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>User</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th><th>Sunday</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($resource)) { 
    if($row->day_of_week == "Monday") { 
        echo "<tr><td>{$row->user_id}</td><td>{$row->start_time} - {$row->end_time}</td>";
    }
    if($row->day_of_week == "Sunday") { 
        echo "<td>{$row->start_time} - {$row->end_time}</td></tr>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<td>{$row->start_time} - {$row->end_time}</td>";  
    }
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This assumes you have a record for every day for every user - I don't know whether that's actually what you have in your database, too.